# RewriteRule Pattern Problem after RewriteBase called

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want my js-files in the folder *scripts* to be redirected to a php which handels the caching. So the *.htaccess* looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /eval/widget/scripts
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js$ func.php?src=$1
```

The filename (without extension) should be passed to the php-file, but instead the *src* parameter is 'scripts/JAVASCRIPT_FILENAME'. What's wrong with this? Seems like RewriteBase doesn't set it correctly...

Comment: In which directory you have placed the .htaccess, in scripts directory?

Comment: @Zimbabao nope, in the widget-dir.

Comment: You understanding of RewriteBase is incorrect. You just change your rewrite rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rewrite rule to

```
RewriteRule ^.*?/(.*)\.js$ func.php?src=$1
```

You understanding of RewriteBase is incorrect.

Comment: that means the pattern of the RewriteRule is relative to the .htaccess location but the file in the second parameter is relative to the RewriteBase??

Comment: Yes, after appending new url is reinjected into server processing. But use RedirectVase only when url physical paths are diff from server paths. Here is from docs "If your webserver's URLs are not directly related to physical file paths, you will need to use RewriteBase in every .htaccess file where you want to use RewriteRule directives". If you have used